# ¿Como Establecer Auth con un Usuario en Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

Tengo un Login Personalizado en un proyecto laravel, **no** estoy usando `composer require laravel/ui`. sin embargo en mi Controlador *LoginController* quiero establecer una sesión usando Auth.

---

Rutas de Acceso del proyecto

[image: rutas de acceso al Proyecto]

---

*LoginController.php*

```
 public function login(Request $request)
 {
    $obj_Persona = Persona::verificarCredenciales($request);
    
    Auth::setSession($obj_Persona); //quiero hacer algo asi con Auth, esta linea es ilustrativa.
    //codigo del return redirect
 }
```

Esto con la finalidad de que otros controladores puedan usar la funcionalidad `Auth::id();` ó `Auth::user();` pero usando mi propio modelo en vez del user que viene por defecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

estuve viendo la documentacion y encontre información util en los siguientes links:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods

basicamente laravel tiene estas 2 formas de autenticar `Auth::login($user);` y `Auth::attempt($credentials)` que equivaldrian mas o menos a lo que quiero hacer.

al final tuve que usar las variables de sesion propias de php y crearme un middleware, es lo mas cercano que llegue a tener un login personalizado sin usar `composer require laravel/ui`

Comment: Yo si lo puede hacer con los enlaces y la información que dejaste. Te voy a dejar el ejemplo para que veas como lo realice

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo puede hacer sin la necesidad de paquetes:

**UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\RegisterUsersRequest; // Validar informacion de los datos de registro de usuarios
use App\Http\Requests\ValidatedAuthUserRequest; // Validación de información de los datos de registro de usuarios

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('users.login.login');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        return view('users.login.register');
    }

    public function signup (RegisterUsersRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        User::create($request->only("name", "email") + ["password" => $user->encrypt($request->password)]);
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }


    public function authenticate(ValidatedAuthUserRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
           $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('notes');
        }
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ]);

    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        //Invalida la sesión y genera una nueva
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        // Genera un nuevo Token
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

Ahora, veamos las rutas

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/register', [UsersController::class, 'register'])->name('users.register'); // muestra el formulario de registro
Route::post('/signup', [UsersController::class, 'signup'])->name('users.signup'); // Proceso de registro de usuario

Route::get('/login', [UsersController::class, 'index'])->name('login')->middleware('guest'); // si estoy autenticado, guest no me mostrar el login
Route::post('/login', [UsersController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('users.auth'); // Proceso de login

Route::post('/logout', [UsersController::class, 'logout'])->name('users.logout'); // Cierre de Sesión
```

Modelo

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function encrypt ($pass)
    {
        return Hash::make($pass);;
    }
}
```

Ahora, veamos cómo validar y mostrar la vista según el usuario logueado:

esta es la vista de `notes.index`

```
@extends('layouts.layouts')

@section('title-app', 'Notes')

@section('content')

    <h2> Notas del usuario {{ Auth::user()->name }} </h2>

    <a href="{{ route('notes.create') }}"> Created Notes </a>

    @foreach ($notes as $note)
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="{{ route('notes.show', $note) }}"> {{ $note->body }} </a> </li>
        </ul>
    @endforeach

    {{ $notes->links() }}
@endsection
```

Con `Auth::user()` se puede ver o mostrar la vista según el usuario logueado.

Espero les sirva.

Comment: Una pregunta, de donde sacaste el RegisterUsersRequest y el ValidatedAuthUserRequest? Parece que no se genera al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto de laravel, será que utilizas el php artisan make:auth?

Comment: ``` RegisterUsersRequest y el ValidatedAuthUserRequest ``` es un FormRequest. Es una manera de validar formularios